# WSO2: Get MQRFH2 header from incoming IBM MQ message

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am reading a queue using WSO2 and trying to get `MQRHF2.usr` values from the incoming message.
To be more certain I am using a PayloadFactory mediator to create a JSON payload. I found the correct path for `MQMD` fields but I couldn't find the right path to the `MQRFH2` header.
This is example where `$trp:JMS_IBM_MsgType` works and `$trp:JMS_MQRFH2_usr_property` doesn't:

```
<payloadFactory description="Build JSON payload from XML request" media-type="json">
                <format>{
                    "mqmd_messageType": "$1",
                    "mqrfh_usr_property": "$2"
                }</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:JMS_IBM_MsgType"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:JMS_MQRFH2_usr_property"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
```

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [wire logs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Debugging+Mediation#DebuggingMediation-Viewingwirelogs) in the WSO2 server and verify whether the transport header is receiving properly. Transport headers are not case sensitive. So, please make sure that you are using the correct header name in the Xpath.